# I want to sqoop data using sqoop import job into hive column partitioned table. How can we do this?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop, partitioning

I have a hive table partitioned on country column.
My RDBMS columns are as follows:

```
id int, fname varchar(45), lname varchar(45), email varchar(45), password varchar(45), street varchar(45), city varchar(45), state varchar(45), zipcode varchar(45), c_time timestamp
```

sample data: 
1,Richard,Hernandez,XXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXX,6303 Heather Plaza,Brownsville,TX,69696,2017-07-20 20:24:17.0

Sqoop Job:

```
    sqoop job --create customer_partition -- import --connect jdbc:mysql://host/serverName 
    --username root -P --table customers --check-column c_time --incremental lastmodified 
--last-value 0 --merge-key id --target-dir '/user/cloudera/partitionedTables/customers_partition/' 
    --fields-terminated-by ',' --hive-import 
    --hive-table customers_partition --hive-partition-key "state";
```

Hive partitioned Table:

```
create external table customers_partition(id int, fname varchar(64), lname varchar(64), email varchar(64), 
password varchar(64), street varchar(45), city varchar(45), zipcode varchar(64), cob_dt timestamp)
partitioned by (state varchar(45))
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
location '/hdfsPath/customers_partition/';
```

After sqoop import in hdfs folder output file contains data as below format:

```
1,Richard,Hernandez,XXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXX,6303 Heather Plaza,Brownsville,TX,69696,2017-07-20 20:24:17.0
which points to same columns same as RDBMS columns. 

When I perform hive query: select * from customers_partition; showing 0 records found in hive.
```

This is because the hive table column arrangement because of partition is different from normal RDBMS table column arrangement.

How can we solve this issue. I want to sqoop import data directly into hive partition table and records need to be updated when ever i run this sqoop job. If I am wrong is there any alternative way to do this?

Also how to perform same using two or more hive partitioned columns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `--hive-partition-value` arguments. The partition value must be a string.

Since you are using `sqoop job --create` `--last-value 0` is not required. Please remove it.

Comment: Is there any way to perform dynamic data import into partitioned columns instead of giving values? Also there should be RDBMS columns sequence and hive colunms partitions should be same. Pls explain me on this.

Comment: Yes, here is reference https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/43982/sqoop-insert-into-partitioned-table.html